# SQL (php)Get value from row when given another. For example get country when given Name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
+-------+----------------+
| Name  |    Country     |
+-------+----------------+
| Steve | United States  |
| Bill  | United kingdom |
+-------+----------------+
```

What I'm trying to do is get the country associated with the name. For instance: If I select in a php dropdown menu the name "Steve" it gives me an outpout with "United states" to import to another table.

I already know how to use an dropdown menu to import data. I just need to know how to get the country as output.

Comment: `Select Country From Table Where Name = 'Steve'`?  I don't understand the question.

Comment: For instance, I select the name "Steve". I want the country associated with that name in this case "United States" in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
$name = "Steve"; //however you get your data from dropdown menu

$query = 'SELECT Country FROM table WHERE Name = "' . $name . '"';
$data = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
$country = $row['Country'];
```

Comment: If you downvote at least say why - then I can learn why i am wrong and improve myself. This is a community to help.